# Помогите исправить код загрузки изображения на сервер

Tags: php, html, ajax, изображения

Заливаю картинки на сервер с помощью ajax. Собственно ничего не заливается.
Уже пробовал  советы из др. веток:
echo var_dump($_FILES);
print_r($_FILES);
Результат: = ARRAY(0) { }, ARRAY ( )
Запрос уходит нормально и как бы:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVSAZZ8J4WT5KQfzX
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hiihf"; filename="1111.jpg"
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVSAZZ8J4WT5KQfzX--

При том что при обычной отправке, через форму данные есть в массиве $_FILES, но все равно не заливается картинка в нужную папку.

```html
<div id='pre_label_t8'></div>
<div id='daad'><input type='file' id='hiihf' name='hiihf'></div>
```

```
$savata = $_SESSION['login'];
if (isset($_FILES['hiihf'])){ 
$data = $_FILES['hiihf'];  
$tmp = $data['tmp_name'];
$info = @getimagesize($_FILES['hiihf']['tmp_name']); 
    if (preg_match('{image/(.*)}is', $info['mime'], $p)){   
        $newwidth1 = 250;  $newheight1 = 250;
        $newname1 = $imgdor.$savata.".".basename($info['mime']); 
        $der = basename($info['mime']);
        global  $der;
        }
    if(resize1($tmp, $newwidth1, $newname1)){
        echo 'done';
        }else{   
        echo "error";
        } 
        

//обновление записи в базе
$format = $savata.".".$der;
$nvata = $savata;
if ($der != ''){
$query = mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE `o_im` SET `o_lab` = '{$format}' WHERE `o_author` = '{$savata}' and `type_dost` = '2'");
} 
}

 function resize1($photo_src, $width, $name){  
 $parametr = getimagesize($photo_src);  
 list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($photo_src);  
 $new_width1 = "250";  
 $new_height = "250";
 $newpic = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width1, $new_height);  
 switch ( $parametr[2] ) {  
 case 1: $image = imagecreatefromgif($photo_src);  
 break;  
 case 2: $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($photo_src);  
 break;  
 case 3: $image = imagecreatefrompng($photo_src);  
 break;  
 }  
 imagecopyresampled($newpic, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width1, $new_height, 
 $width_orig, $height_orig);  
 imagejpeg($newpic, $name, 100);  
 return true;  
 }
```

```js
$('#hiihf').change(function() {
  var ff = new FormData();
  console.log(this.files);
  ff.append("hiihf", this.files[0]);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "system/labels/upload.php",
    data: ff,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(html) {
      $("#pre_label_t8").html(html);
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Еще актуально. Заметил такую особенность. Вообще  у меня данный скрипт используется на двух страницах. Так вот на одной - он работает. А этот нет. Сравнил все. И код и запросы и ответы. Единственное различие словил, такое: В рабочем 
    Content type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7F2oanOtunLmEGfF
, а в не рабочем такой вот 
    Content-Type:false
p.s. может из за этого не работает корректно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Обернуть input в тег form

```
<form id="YOUR_FORM" method="POST" action="system/labels/upload.php">
     <div id='daad'><input type='file' id='hiihf' name='hiihf'></div>
</form>
```

2)  Вызвать submit у формы (если конечно нужно сделать вызов по change)

```
$('#hiihf').change(function() {
    $('#YOUR_FORM').submit();
});
```

3)  Повесить обработчик на submit твоей формы

```
$('#YOUR_FORM').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Убираем действие по умолчанию
    var FILES = new FormData($(this)[0]); // Здесь вся дата с твоей формы, включая файлы
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        data: FILES,
        // ...
    });
});
```

4) Не совсем понял о "не той папке", т.к. не увидел в коде самой записи, но можно почитать об этом здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59789/discussion-on-answer-by-oleg-reym------).